# How can I make a whole column bold?

Tags: html, css, html-table

I have a big HTML table and I want to easily make the 16th column bold. Using `<colgroup>` and `<col>` is obviously not working:

```
<HTML>
<BODY>
<TABLE BORDER='1'>
<colgroup>
<col span='15'>
<col style='font-weight: bold;'>
</colgroup>
<TR>
<TH>&nbsp;</TH><TH>0</TH><TH>0.5</TH><TH>1</TH><TH>1.5</TH><TH>2</TH><TH>2.5</TH><TH>3</TH><TH>3.5</TH><TH>4</TH><TH>4.5</TH><TH>5</TH><TH>5.5</TH><TH>6</TH><TH>6.5</TH><TH>7</TH><TH>7.5</TH><TH>8</TH><TH>8.5</TH><TH>9</TH><TH>9.5</TH><TH>10</TH><TH>10.5</TH><TH>11</TH><TH>11.5</TH><TH>12</TH><TH>12.5</TH><TH>13</TH><TH>13.5</TH><TH>14</TH><TH>14.5</TH><TH>15</TH><TH>15.5</TH><TH>16</TH>
</TR>
<TR BGCOLOR='#DDDDDD'>
<TH ALIGN='LEFT'>ARG-21_VSDS (0):</TH><TD>0.00</TD><TD>0.00</TD><TD>0.00</TD><TD>0.00</TD><TD>0.00</TD><TD>0.00</TD><TD>0.00</TD><TD>0.00</TD><TD>0.00</TD><TD>0.00</TD><TD>0.00</TD><TD>0.00</TD><TD>0.00</TD><TD>0.00</TD><TD>0.00</TD><TD>0.00</TD><TD>0.00</TD><TD>0.00</TD><TD>0.00</TD><TD>0.00</TD><TD>0.00</TD><TD>0.01</TD><TD>0.01</TD><TD>0.05</TD><TD>0.13</TD><TD>0.33</TD><TD>0.59</TD><TD>0.82</TD><TD>0.93</TD><TD>0.97</TD><TD>0.99</TD><TD>1.00</TD><TD>1.00</TD>
</TR>
<TR BGCOLOR='#DDDDDD'>
<TH ALIGN='LEFT'>ARG-21_VSDS (1):</TH><TD>1.00</TD><TD>1.00</TD><TD>1.00</TD><TD>1.00</TD><TD>1.00</TD><TD>1.00</TD><TD>1.00</TD><TD>1.00</TD><TD>1.00</TD><TD>1.00</TD><TD>1.00</TD><TD>1.00</TD><TD>1.00</TD><TD>1.00</TD><TD>1.00</TD><TD>1.00</TD><TD>1.00</TD><TD>1.00</TD><TD>1.00</TD><TD>1.00</TD><TD>1.00</TD><TD>0.99</TD><TD>0.99</TD><TD>0.95</TD><TD>0.87</TD><TD>0.67</TD><TD>0.41</TD><TD>0.18</TD><TD>0.07</TD><TD>0.03</TD><TD>0.01</TD><TD>0.00</TD><TD>0.00</TD>
</TR>
</TABLE>
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use [CSS's `nth-of-type` selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-of-type) to do this easily with no additional HTML markup required:

```
td:nth-of-type(16) {
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you should use classes on your  tags and then target the  within that class. for example:

```
<tr class="bold">some <td> tags</tr>

tr.bold td{
 font-weight:bold;
}
```